# Java vs Python Regular Expression

Tags: java, python, regex

i wrote a regular expression to match a string to be in range 0-255.

my regular expression is `([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])`

i know my regular expression is technically incorrect as  it will be true after matching the first character of the string matches [0-9]
so even "1234" will be matched .

now i write it in python..

```
a="2514"
>>> if(re.match("([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])",a)):
...     print("yes")
```

output = yes

but when i write it in java ..

```
String s="2514";
        if(s.matches("([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])"))
        {
            System.out.println("yes");
        }
```

output is nothing

Comment: Because you have to read the docs and use the method that corresponds in function, not name. I had the same problem starting out with Python, but now I forgot the Java method names.

Comment: with ^ and $ added for defining what the beginning and ending must be it will not be different.
your python code asks the question 'is there a match in this input given a regex'.
your java code asks the question 'matches this input my regex?'
so your examples are asking different questions, and as result the validation is different. (equivalent would be 'contains input a certain string vs. is input equal to certain string if we were just string searching instead of regex searching)

Comment: `matches` requires a full string match in Java, while `re.match` in Python only anchors the match at the start of the string.

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs of `matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--):

> Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.

This is similar to [Python `fullmatch()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch).

---

`find()` is similar to Pythons `match()`:

> Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.

Comment: You were looking for `fullmatch`, I think

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yeah, I guess you're right. I was actually answering the question from the Java perspective pointing out that `match` ~ `find`, not `matches`. However, re-reading the question I realize that OP was probably looking for the Pythonic way of doing `matches`. I'll clarify.